# How can I use pywinauto to perform click operation when user is not logged in to the system?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, remote-desktop, pywinauto

I am currently using pywinauto to auto refresh power BI file through windows task scheduler. script works well and it does the job well if I am logged in in the system. if I just let the script run using the scheduler it is not able to detect the active desktop to move the mouse cursor.

Error I am currently getting is "There is no active desktop required for moving mouse cursor". win.Home.click_input() this is causing an issue while running this in the remote computer and not able to perform click operation.

I am using the following script.

```
import time
import os
import sys
import psutil
from pywinauto import Application

os.system('start "" "' + Filepath + '"')

# Connect pywinauto
print("Identifying Power BI window")
app = Application(backend = 'uia').connect(path = PROCNAME)
win = app.window(title_re = '.*Power BI Desktop')
        
time.sleep(3)
win.wait("enabled", timeout = 300)
win.Save.wait("enabled", timeout = 300)
win.set_focus()
win.Home.click_input()
win.Save.wait("enabled", timeout = 300)
win.wait("enabled", timeout = 300)
    
# Refresh
print("Refreshing Started"
win.Refresh.click_input()
time.sleep(3)
win.wait("enabled", timeout = 300)

#Save
win.type_keys("^S")
time.sleep(3)
win.wait("enabled", timeout = 300)
```

Is there any possible solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not allow the 'keyboard' to be used while the screen is locked. It is a security thing.

You may need to find the exact button or field you wish to activate then use `click()` and not `click_input()`.

This means `send_keys` or `type_keys` will not work but `set_text` will.

Answer (score 0):

The click_input() class is need to logged on to OS.